# How can you print the decision tree of a RandomForestClassifier

Tags: python, random-forest, scikit-learn

Recently, I have noticed that there is a method `sklearn.tree.export_graphviz` documented [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html).

However, I do not know how I can apply it to a `RandomForestClassifier`.

I have tried the following naive code but it does not work, and I do not know how I can get one of the trees from a `RandomForestClassifier`:

```
print('Training...')
forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
forest = forest.fit( train_data[0::,1::], train_data[0::,0] )


print('Predicting...')
output = forest.predict(test_data).astype(int)

if sys.version_info >= (3,0,0):
    predictions_file = open("myfirstforest.csv", 'w', newline='')
else:
    predictions_file = open("myfirstforest.csv", 'wb')


tree.export_graphviz(forest, out_file='tree.dot')
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your RandomForest creates 100 tree, so you can not print these in one step. Try iterate over the trees in the forest and print them out one by one:

```
from sklearn import tree
i_tree = 0
for tree_in_forest in forest.estimators_:
    with open('tree_' + str(i_tree) + '.dot', 'w') as my_file:
        my_file = tree.export_graphviz(tree_in_forest, out_file = my_file)
    i_tree = i_tree + 1
```

If you want to know the actual parameters of the trees like splitting attribute (feature), splitting value (threshold), node samples (n_node_samples) etc., you can use `print getmembers(tree_in_forest.tree_)` in the for cycle. To use one of these parameters, eg. threshold, use this: `tree_in_forest.tree_.threshold` It returns with a list.

Comment: What is `getmembers`?

Comment: @Jarad It's from `inspect` but you don't really need it here.